# Find addresses using pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers

```
int main()
{
    //case 1
    char animal[20] = "bear";
    char *p;
    p = animal;

    cout << &animal << endl; //find the address of animal[0] using &

    cout << p << endl; //cannot find the address as t does and print out 'bear'


    //case 2
    int val = 23;
    int *t = &val;

    cout << t << endl; //find the address of val

    return 0;
}
```

Q1.
I don't understand why I cannot find *animal[0]* address by typing *p* and I thought it will be  the same situation as in *int pointer* case.
Q2.
I saw books using *(int *)p* to find the *animal* address and someone says it is a bad practice. I wonder how can I find the *animal[0]* address by using *pointer p*.

Comment: `delete [] p;` and `delete [] t;` are very incorrect code

Comment: oh yeah, so only if using 'new', right?